# Cache miss ? how can I see that?

Tags: c, performance, optimization

Given the following code :

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
  counter += myArray[i];
}
```

And the Loop unrolling version :

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i+=4)
{
  counter1 += myArray[i+0];
  counter2 += myArray[i+1];
  counter3 += myArray[i+2];
  counter4 += myArray[i+3];
}

total = counter1+ counter2 + counter3+ counter4;
```

1. Why do we have a cache miss in the first version ?
2. Is the second version has indeed a better performance than the 1st ? why ?

Regards

Comment: What makes you think that there is a cache miss in the first version?

Comment: I'm not sure there'll be a great deal of difference...

Comment: Smells like homework too much...

Comment: Actually not homework at all , just wondering before my upcoming exam in computer organization ...

Comment: The second version is theoretically slightly faster because the loop overhead is reduced, but I don't see any cache miss in the first version

Comment: Most compilers these days are smart enough to do loop unrolling automatically.  I would be very surprised if there was a difference between the generated code for the two versions.

Comment: I don't know about a cache miss, but your code will read past the end of the array if n mod 4 != 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why do we have a cache miss in the first version ?

As Oli points out in the comments. This question is unfounded. If the data is already in the cache, then there will be no cache misses.

That aside, there is no difference in memory access between your two examples. So that will not likely be a factor in any performance difference between them.

> Is the second version has indeed a better performance than the 1st ? why ?

Usually, the thing to do is to actually measure. But in this particular example, I'd say that it will likely be faster. Not because of better cache access, but because of the loop-unrolling.

The optimization that you are doing is called "Node-Splitting", where you separate the `counter` variable for the purpose of breaking the dependency chain.

However, in this case, you are doing a trivial reduction operation. Many modern compilers are able to recognize this pattern and do this node-splitting for you.

**So is it faster? Most likely.** But you should check to see if the compiler does it for you.

---

**For the record:** I just tested this on Visual Studio 2010.
And I am quite surprised that it is ***not able*** to do this optimization.

```
; 129  : 
; 130  :     int counter = 0;
; 131  : 
; 132  :     for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR n$[rsp]
    xor edx, edx
    test    ecx, ecx
    jle SHORT $LN1@main
$LL3@main:

; 133  :     {
; 134  :         counter += myArray[i];

    add edx, DWORD PTR [rax]
    add rax, 4
    dec rcx
    jne SHORT $LL3@main
$LN1@main:

; 135  :     }
```

Visual Studio 2010 does not seem to be capable of performing "Node Splitting" for this (trivial) example...